How to use Photoswipe Lightbox with Laravel
do you know how to use the PhotoSwipe library with Laravel? I would like to ask for some help. I am working on a project using Laravel Backpack, and I am referring to the PhotoSwipe library to implement a zoom feature when clicking on an image: https://photoswipe.com/getting-started/.
First, I installed the library and set everything up according to its documentation. Then, I created a file named swipe.js in the resources/js/ directory with the content:
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox';
import 'photoswipe/style.css';

const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
    gallery: 'body',
    children: '.enable-zoom-image',
    showHideAnimationType: 'zoom',
    pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe')
});
lightbox.init();

Next, I imported it into the vite.config.js file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/swipe.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

Then, I continued to import it into the ui.php file in the config/backpack directory:
'vite_scripts' => [ // resource file_path
        'resources/js/swipe.js',
        // 'resources/js/app.js',
    ],

Finally, I customized the view of the element that needs zooming:
<div class="enable-zoom-image">
    <a href="{{ $image }}"
       data-pswp-width="1669"
       data-pswp-height="2500"
       rel="noreferrer">
        <div class="d-flex py-1 align-items-center enable-zoom-image"
             style="width: {{ $width ?? '250px' }}; height: {{ $height ?? '150px' }};">
            <img src="{{ $image }}" style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                 onerror="this.src='/images/car-default.jpg'">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

After these steps, I checked the console on the web and saw that the library was successfully added in the elements tab and in the network tab. However, the zoom feature is still not working. When I click on an image, the system simply redirects to the image link instead of zooming in.

Did you figure this out. am trying to do the same and getting the same result
